# Floor function inequality of multiplication

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

In a final step of a homework, I want to deduce that 
$$n\lfloor(n-1)!e\rfloor+2\le \lfloor n!e\rfloor+1$$
I'm unable to see whether this is true in general that 
$$n\lfloor a\rfloor+1\le \lfloor na\rfloor$$
where $n$ is a natural number or do I need to use power series of $e$ to do some reasoning. Thank you.

Comment: Let $a=0.012345678910\dots$, and $n$ fairly small, like $8$.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376720/for-which-a-is-n-lfloor-a-rfloor1-le-lfloor-na-rfloor-true-for-all-suffici

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not in general true that $n\lfloor a\rfloor+1\le \lfloor na\rfloor$.  In particular, if $n,a$ are both naturals, the floor will not matter and you would be asking for $na+1 \le na$ which is false.  So yes, you need the power series of $e$.

Comment: Ok, modify a bit, let $a$ be irrational.

Comment: @mezhang:  even with $a$ irrational, if it is just a little bit bigger than a natural (by less than $\frac 1n$) it will still be false.

Comment: You are right. I will think about the power series argument.

Comment: I checked, the statement is false even for e.

Answer (score 2):

You need only one false value of n to invalidate the inequation. Let's try with the first natural number n=1 :

```
    From n⌊(n−1)!e⌋+2 ≤ ⌊n!e⌋+1 
    we get ⌊(0)!e⌋+2 ≤ ⌊0!e⌋+1 
    and ⌊e⌋+2 ≤ ⌊e⌋+1.
```

Wich is obviously false.